# PDOexception - 'could not find driver'

Tags: macos, pdo, mamp, php

I woork on my local site with MAMP. Everything was going right till yesterday. Now, when I run my code,  I get a : "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'..." It seems that  I have non installed driver but it worked well until this day. How can I fix this problem ?

Best, 
Newben

Comment: For informations, I  uncommented on my php.ini file the correct extensions : extension=pdo_mysql.so,etc.. Btw, perhaps there is a problem with the error warnings I changed yesterday !

Comment: Did you changed the PDO DSN? Maybe you have a typo there, like an invalid DSN prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Sfblaauw's solution didn't work but it helped me identify the problem. First I installed php5-mysql using MacPorts:

```
sudo port install php5-mysql
```

During installation, I got the following warning:

> Your php.ini contains a line that will prevent php5-mysql
>   and other PHP extensions from working. To fix this,
>   edit /opt/local/etc/php5/php.ini and delete this line:
>
> extension_dir = "/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626"

I commented out the line and restarted Apache. Everything seems to work fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed MacPorts? If your answer is "yes" open your Shell and type:

1. `cd ~/`
2. `sudo nano .profile`
3. change: 
   `export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH` 
   replace with:
   `export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/:$PATH`
4. close your Shell and re-open it

This is all. I found the solution here: [thewebfactory](http://thewebfactory.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/symfony-2-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver-with-mamp-2-0/)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try and  I'll let you know.Best, Newben