# Homestead - Laravel 4.2 - PGSQL - PDOException - could not find driver

Tags: postgresql, pdo, laravel-4

hopefully somebody can help.

I have a new installation of homestead with a laravel 4.2 application making use of postgresql.

The error in the log file when trying to interact with the db is: *local.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in :*

I have tested the following:
1. According to a phpinfo(); page php is configured with pdo + pdo_pgsql
2. Verified no 1 with the following code:
```php

```
foreach (PDO::getAvailableDrivers() as $driver)
{
    echo $driver . '<br />';
}

$dbh = new PDO ('pgsql:host=xxxx;dbname=xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx')
or die ("Error");

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('pgsql:host=xxxx;dbname=xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx');
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from users') as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

```
which produced the following output:

`mysql
pgsql
sqlite
Array ( [id] => 1 .........................................`

3. I can run *php artisan migrate* and *php artisan tinker* and create the db tables and create db entries.

Thus I have determined the following:
1. PHP is running and configured correctly via both web and cli
2. Postgresql is running and accessible via artisan
3. I don't know why the laravel web interaction with pgsql is not working

I am at my wits end and would appreciate any help.

I have tried the following articles in my search for sanity:

- [SO 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912040/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)
- [SO 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329302/laravel-error-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt update everything:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After wasting time on nginx configuration, php5-fpm configuration and obviously php ini configuration a simple update and upgrade fixed all my problems.